# How can i make a sdl window unmovable

Tags: c, sdl-2

I am making a game in C using sdl2 and opengl and I want to make my windows unmovable. I've been investigating in flags but I didn't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a flag, but you may disable the resizing: SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE in SDL_CreateWindow and then force the window to be at specific coordinates in each refresh cycle in your program: SDL_SetWindowPosition.

So if the user tries to move the window, it will immediately jump back on its own. That can be conditional as well, check if the window was moved - SDL_GetWindowPosition etc.